# how to push javafx tableview data into sqlite database?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, collections, javafx-11

I'm working on a store management app. Now I want to display all new products
in a `TableView` before pushing it into database. To add new products to `TableView` I'm using a `List<Product>` and I can see all new products to a `TableView` but if I try to push them to the database with `addbatch()`, and `executeBatch()` method, I'm getting error sqlite file lock database. I have set `autocommit` to *false*. Here is my code:

```java
public void validerFacture() throws SQLException {
    String ajoutProduits = BaseDeDonne.AJOUTER_PRODUITS;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        connection = BaseDeDonne.connect();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(ajoutProduits);
        for (Produits p : produits) {
            ps.setInt(1, p.getQuantite());
            ps.setString(2, p.getCategorie());
            ps.setString(3, p.getTaille());
            ps.setString(4, p.getDesignation());
            ps.setDouble(5, p.getPrixEnGros());
            ps.setDouble(6, p.getPrixUnitaire());
            ps.setDouble(7, p.getPrixVente());
            ps.setDouble(8, p.getMarge());
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();

    } catch (SQLException b) {
        b.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

You can see the SQL query to insert objects to database:

```java
public static final String AJOUTER_PRODUITS = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_PRODUIT + "("
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_QUANTITE + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_CATEGORIE+ ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_TAILLE + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_DESIGANTION + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_PRIX_ACHAT + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_PRIX_REVIENT + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_PRIX_VENTE + ","
            + COLUMN_PRODUIT_PRIX_MARGE
              +")"
            + " VALUES " +
            "(" + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + ")";
```

I tried to use a loop to insert `List<Product>` to the database but nothing happen to the database or I get Slite Lock database file.

Comment: Close your PreparedStatement and close your Connection.  The easiest way to do this is to place their creation in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements:  `try (Connection connection = BaseDeDonne.connect()) {` and `try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(ajoutProduits)) {`.  Doing this will guarantee they are closed automatically.

Comment: [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Still getting sqlite busy error.

Comment: Here is an example of how your database handler should look. -> https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample/blob/master/src/sqlitepersonexample/DBHandler.java.